# csvファイルのデータをpythonのmatplolibでプロットする方法

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib, csv

まず、csvファイルの中身についてですが、以下のようになっており1列目から順に`x1,x2,1,y`となっています。(実際は101行4列)

```
"x1","x2","1","y"
-0.626,-0.620,1,0.282
0.183,0.042,1,1.732
-0.835,-0.910,1,-0.293
1.595,0.158,1,2.506
0.329,-0.654,1,0.615
```

そこで、横軸を`a*x1+b*x2`,縦軸を`y`と設定しプロットしたいのですがうまくいきません。それぞれ一行づつデータを取り出し、変数`a,b`を掛け合わせプロットするにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

aとbの設定がよくわかりませんが固定値として回答させてもらいます。またCSVファイルは、aaa.csvとしました。

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    data = np.loadtxt('aaa.csv', delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
    print("data\n",data)
    a = 1
    b = 2
    x1 = data[:,0]
    x2 = data[:,1]
    y = data[:,3]
    print(x1,x2,y)
    x = a*x1+b*x2
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.scatter(x,y)
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
```

こんな感じでは？

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます。説明が抜けていましたね、a,bは固定値です。

Comment: 実行結果を回答に含めていただくと評価しやすかったです。